# How can I draw low - medium - high chart in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-design, dart-ui

I want to draw a chart of BMI levels on my flutter app. Something similar to this image [image]

Is there some package I can use to help me achieve this or do you have any suggestions on how can I draw something similar to it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is awesome package https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts

just see the example app, here one of the list below

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate. its really great package! I found so many useful things I was looking for.